# How to edit unity popup menu?

Tags: unity, gnome, themes

I want to create Ubuntu Touch theme for Ubuntu desktop. I have accomplished  [this](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Ubuntu-Touch+%28Unity%29?content=168490)  so far. I'm left with one thing; and that is adding an orange border to the top panel popup menus. 
How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: What icon set do you use?

Comment: Thanks!! Icon theme used is Dalisha :http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Dalisha?content=166286

Answer (score 3):

I fixed that by editing `gtk-widgets.css` .menu section. It looks like this now:

```
.menu {
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #f07746;
    background-color: @menu_bg_color;
    color: @menu_fg_color;
```